# adding a .jar file through to a java project through specific code

Tags: java, plugins, jar

I need to make such a plugin a storage that contain some .jar files and i need to add these jar files to my java project through code and **not** through these methods http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29 in order to be able to dynamically update my code every time a plugin is addded.
For example , I will put a directory on a server called Plugins that contain .jar files representing different plugins , I need that every time i execute the code I search the directory for new .jar files and if found i can add them to the java project.

Comment: Please edit your question wtih code samples etc. And please, please, use punctuation!

Comment: @HoneyBadger check the edited post for more details.

Comment: Your first sentence (the original question before the edit) is still not easy tor read due to the lack of punctuation. I had to read it 5 times before I had some sort of idea what you are asking. I wont have an answer to this question, but I'm just trying to help you making a sensible question which may receive an answer.

Comment: This is the best way 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime